# META Web Dev CSS Question about color and font size

Tags: html, css

Brand new to coding, just started the META Back-End Certificate on Coursera, and I am having trouble with one of the quizzes. We are provided the HTML, and then we have to write CSS to meet certain criteria. I have listed the Prompt, HTML, CSS, and errors below:

Prompt:

```
"
Open the styles.css file.

Add a CSS rule for the body element that sets the background color to #E0E0E2.

Add a CSS rule for the h1 element that sets the text color to: #721817.

Add a CSS rule for the h2 element that sets the text color to: #721817.

Add a CSS rule for the center-text CSS class that aligns the text to center.

Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id logo. Set its left and right margins to auto and changes its display to a block element.

Add a CSS rule for all span elements that are children of h2 elements that sets the text color to #FA9F42 and its font size to 0.75em.

Add a CSS rule for the HTML element with the id copyright. Set its top padding to 12 pixels and its font size to 0.75em."
```

HTML Code that was provided for the quiz:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Little Lemon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="logo.png" id="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="center-text">
        <h1>Our Menu</h1>
        <h2>Falafel <span>NEW</span></h2>
        <p>Chickpea, herbs, spices.</p>
        <h2>Pasta Salad</h2>
        <p>Pasta, vegetables, mozzarella.</p>
        <h2>Fried Calamari</h2>
        <p>Squid, buttermilk.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="center-text">
        <p id="copyright">
            Copyright Little Lemon
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

"

CSS code that I wrote:

```
body {
background-color: #E0E0E2;
}
h1 {
    color: #721817;
}
h2 {
    color: #721817;
}

.center-text{
    text-align: center;
}

#logo {
    display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

span {
    color: #fa9f42;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

#copyright {
    padding-top: 12px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

When I submit, the autograder on Coursera is returning the two error messages:

"Failed - ✗ The 'NEW' labels within  tags should have a color of '#fa9f42' (+ 1 related test)"

"Failed - ✗ The element with the ID 'copyright' should have a font-size of 0.75em"

I am not sure why these two tests are coming up as failed, as it appears that the webpage view reflects that the 'copyright' font size is correct, and that the 'NEW' labels within  do in fact have that color. Any ideas why this is coming up as wrong?

Thanks anyone and everyone!

Comment: The second to last prompt asks to modify span elements that are children of h2 elements, however, your code modifies all span elements. Try replacing span in the CSS to h2 > span.

Comment: This was exactly the right change! Thank you very much for your help Caeden :)

Comment: No problem! I'll post my reply as an answer so the status of this post can be changed to answered.

Answer (score 0):

The second to last prompt asks to modify span elements that are children of h2 elements, however, your code modifies all span elements.

To fix this, change

```css
span {
    color: #fa9f42;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

to

```css
h2 > span {
    color: #fa9f42;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

This small change requires all spans to be children of an h2 element in order to be modified, thus, fulfilling the request of the second to last prompt.